# Setting a domain in Veil-Evasion for payload

Tags: penetration-test, antivirus

Can we set a domian, i.e., abccorp.com instead of the IP when we use set LHOST in Veil-Evasion? Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just lookup the IP behind the web server with a DNS lookup. There are plenty of sites that can do this, such as: site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html.

Also, I have to assume you don't know what DNS is. DNS or domain name service is a way for routers/service providers to give friendly names for servers that people want to connect to. For example, instead of typing in the IP address for google, you type in google.com, and a DNS service finds the IP address of the site with that domain name so you don' t have to memorize a long chain of numbers for every site you visit.

Comment: The IP is blocked by the content filter and only certain  domain names are allowed. That's why I need to set the Domain instead of IP. Please answer if you are familiar with the topic, veil and if you are an experienced pentester thanks.

Comment: I am familiar with veil (I love their encrypted payload generation). Veil-Evasion is basically just built on Metasploit. So you might get a greater response if you broaden your question to include the Metasploit framework. I'm not sure if you can use a domain at all. But I also have to wonder what kind of firewall/web filter would block domain names and not IP addresses, or vise versa. This doesn't seem to be a veil problem so much as a firewall problem.